# Import error somehow connected with app_labels

Tags: django

**Django==2.2.3**

**Python 3.7**

I get this error:

```
    from yandex.models import YandexGoals
ImportError: cannot import name 'YandexGoals' from 'yandex.models' (/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads1/ads_manager/yandex/models.py)
```

When I stop in my IDE at the event of the exception (namely, I stop at any exception) and evaluate the expression "from yandex.models import YandexGoals", I get this:

```
RuntimeError: Model class yandex_campaigns.models.YandexCampaignCommonTemplate doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Well, the message differs. Let's investigate what we have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'yandex',
    'yandex_campaigns',
]
```

**yandex/models.py**

```
class YandexGoals(models.Model):
    ...
```

**yandex/apps.py**

```
class YandexConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yandex'
```

**yandex_campaigns.apps.py**

```
class YandexCampaignsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yandex_campaigns'
```

To the best ob my ability, I can't see any flaw here. Could you give me a kick?

Comment: At first sight it looks like the `models.py` does not contain a class named `YandexGoals`?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem , I checked once again. It seems to be there. And IDE can see it and autocomplete helps find the necessary model class.